# Help button is not working

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com

I have noticed that "Help" button on https://stackexchange.com is not working.

[image]

Also there is no link to Help in the footer, and https://stackexchange.com/help leads to "Page Not Found".

May I assume "Help" button should be removed from top navigation menu?

Comment: Well, the stackexchange.com code base has just a copy of the "real" code base, they copied the HTML now and forgot to copy the JS.